# Update MySQL table using values in another (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP script which will update one table with a '1' when a date value in another table is greater or equal to the current date. This is based on an id field which is present in both tables. I have tested the following code with no success - it gives an error for the foreach loop:

```php
<?php

$db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '****');
mysql_select_db('db', $db_conn);

$info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_profiles");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($info);

foreach($fetch['user_id'] as $id) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id 
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT user_id
FROM user_profiles
WHERE DATE(profile_value) >= DATE(NOW()) 
AND users.id = user_profiles.user_id)", $db_conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$user_del_result = mysql_query("UPDATE users.block
WHERE user_id = {$row['user_id']}
SET block ='1'
LIMIT 1", $db_conn);                          
}

}
?>
```

Both tables contain the same amount of rows (users).

Any help would be great.

Edit

I have narrowed it down to the following:

```
<?php

$db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '****');
mysql_select_db('db', $db_conn);

$info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_profiles");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($info);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$user_del_result = mysql_query("UPDATE users
WHERE user_id = {$row['id']}
AND WHERE Date(profile_value ) >= DATE(NOW()) 
SET block ='1'", $db_conn);                          
}
?>
```

However the following error is now thrown:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Job.php on line 10

Ok now I'm confused...

```
<?php

$db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
mysql_select_db('_db', $db_conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id 
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT user_id
FROM user_profiles
WHERE DATE(profile_value) >= DATE(NOW()) 
AND users.id = user_profiles.user_id)", $db_conn);

$user_del_result = mysql_query("UPDATE users
WHERE user_id = {$row['id']}
AND WHERE Date(profile_value ) >= DATE(NOW()) 
SET block ='1'", $db_conn);                          
}

?>
```

Error
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Job.php on line 14

Comment: Learn to use mysqli or PDO. With mysql you are vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Hi, it's: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Job.php on line 13" (running on localhost)

Comment: why dont you make the whole process entirely in sql? that way you can make this a sp as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `foreach` statement correctly. You should use it like:

```
foreach ($fetch as $user)
```

Where `$user` will contain you user record; then you can access user columns such as `$user['id']`.

Currently, you are using an array key in the `foreach` statement, not an array, that's why it probably throws an error.

Also, I believe that updating a table based on another table can be done in plain SQL, you don't have to involve PHP and so many queries for this.

Comment: Thanks Andrei - what I am trying to do is create PHP script which will run as a cron task. That fixed the error. However the table is not being set with a '1'?

Comment: You are doing two loops, and within the first one you are executing the same thing. You should drop the first loop as it is useless. Then, the `UPDATE` statement looks wrong. You need to specify what table to update, that is `UPDATE users`. You also do not need any `LIMIT`. You also have to make sure you are using the correct table names and columns. For certainty, open up phpMyAdmin or what you are using, an try executing your SQL. It will help debugging your query.

Comment: You are still doing the first query which you are not using anywhere. And the second query throws that error because you are supplying `$results`, which doesn't exist. Keep the query for `$result` and use that in the `while()` loop you have, and remove that `$info`/`$fetch` stuff you don't use.

Comment: The query in `$results` fetches all records, which then you iterate over in the `while` loop. Therefore you should move it outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think I've pretty much got it.